# Using Avg and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, average

I'm writing a query that needs to compute the average cost of a movie based on each genre.
I am using MySQL to write this query.
So far I have `

```
SELECT 
    MOVIE_NUM,
    MOVIE_GENRE,    
    ROUND(AVG(MOVIE_COST), 2) AS 'AVERAGE COST',
    MOVIE_COST
FROM
    MOVIE
GROUP BY MOVIE_GENRE 
ORDER BY MOVIE_NUM
```

This gives me the following output:

```
MOVIE_NUM  MOVIE_GENRE  AVERAGE COST  MOVIE_COST
1234       FAMILY       39.95         39.95
1235       ACTION       52.72         59.95
1236       DRAMA        58.46         59.95
1237       COMEDY       44.12         29.95
```

However I need it in this format:

```
MOVIE_NUM  MOVIE_GENRE  AVERAGE COST  MOVIE_COST
1234       FAMILY       39.95         39.95
1235       ACTION       52.72         59.95
1236       DRAMA        58.46         59.95
1237       COMEDY       44.12         29.95
1238       DRAMA        58.46         89.95
1239       DRAMA        58.46         25.49
1245       ACTION       52.72         45.49
1246       COMEDY       44.12         58.29
```

Any help is appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sir what is confusing me is that why he GROUP BY clause filters the result?!

Comment: @vladr mysql doesn't support `OVER`

Comment: However you need it this format??? Considering we are not mind readers, what the hell are you asking for?  Your second result has multiple genres, but on what criteria??? Read your question and pretend you are us..now try to answer the question.  Voting to close because you didn't spend enough time asking a valid question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get all records from the same query that you are grouping. Calculate the averages in one query and join against the table:

```
selecct
  m.MOVIE_NUM,
  m.MOVIE_GENRE,
  a.AVGCOST AS 'AVERAGE COST',
  m.MOVIE_COST
from
  MOVIE as m
  inner join (
    select MOVIE_GENRE, round(avg(MOVIE_COST)) as AVGCOST
    from MOVIE
    group by MOVIE_GENRE
  ) as a on a.MOVIE_GENRE = m.MOVIE_GENRE
order by MOVIE_NUM
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be shorter ways of doing this in mysql, as it has some neat group by tricks, but this should work:

```
Select
  m.Movie_Num,
  m.Movie_Genre,    
  gc.Average_Cost,
  m.Movie_Cost
From
  Movie m
    Inner Join (
      Select
        Movie_Genre,
        Round(Avg(Movie_Cost), 2) AS 'Average_Cost'
      From
        Movie
      Group By
        Movie_Genre
      ) as gc
     On m.Movie_Genre = gc.Movie_Genre
Order By 
  m.Movie_Num
```